# Prisma: Difficulty Including explicit Many-to-Many Prisma relation using findMany()

Tags: many-to-many, prisma

I'm having difficulty fetching my data using prisma, I have a many-to-many relationship between `Class` and `Student`

schema.prisma

```
model Class{
  id          BigInt          @id @db.UnsignedBigInt @default(autoincrement())
  name        String          @db.VarChar(10)
  student     classStudent[]  @relation("ClassToStudent")
}

model Student {
  id          BigInt          @id @db.UnsignedBigInt @default(autoincrement())
  name        String          @db.VarChar(255)
  class       classStudent[]  @relation("StudentToClass")
}

model classStudent {
  id          BigInt        @id @db.UnsignedBigInt @default(autoincrement())
  studentId   BigInt        @db.UnsignedBigInt
  classId     BigInt        @db.UnsignedBigInt
  class       Class         @relation("ClassToStudent", fields: [classId], references: [id])
  student     Student       @relation("StudentToClass", fields: [studentId], references: [id])
}
```

example output:

```
"student": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "class": [
      {
        "studentId": 1,
        "teacherId": 3,
        "classId": 2,
        "class": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Science"
        },
        //"teacher": {...}
      },
      ... //each student has many classes
    ],
  },
  ...
]
```

I tried using multiple include in the query

```
const siswa = await prisma.student.findMany({
  include: {
    class: {
      include: {
        class: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

There is not much explanation in the prisma documentation :/